# Adding a rails herokuapp to a subpage of an existing page domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I am creating a rails landing page for a client and he wants the app to be a subpage of his website.

app.herokuapp.com
website.com/app

How can I configure the domain so that when the user types website.com/app
The app.herokuapp.com appears instead?

Edit.
Obs. The client website is big and runs on WordPress installed on domains.com

I am new to rails and the domain services, sorry if it is too of a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

**Heroku must run the rails app in the root of your domain**. So basically what you're trying to do is impossible using just Heroku and whatever domain service.

However the desired result can be achieved by making the whole thing a rails app but with namespaces. This can only work if the website is doesn't require a server to run. i.e it's static with just HTML, CSS and JS but with no framework like Angular or CMS like WordPress. Here's an outline of the steps one would need to take to do that:

1. First of all, to make your "rails app" exist in `/app`, you can move all the "*application* related" routes to an "app" namespace.

In your routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes draw do

    namespace :app do
     # all application routes should be placed in here
    end

end
```

2. You need to move all your *app* related controllers to a `/controllers/app`.
3. All the *application* controllers need have their classes renamed to have the proper namespace. So you need to change every `class WhateverController < ApplicationController` to `class App::WhateverController < ApplicationController`
4. You need to move all the *application* related views to `/views/app`
5. This step is a little tricky. And it's only necessary if the assets (css, javascript) differ between the *website* and *application*. You need to create app.js, website.js, app.css, website.css that will live in `/assets/javascripts` and `/assets/stylesheets` respectively. You also need to create "website" and "app" folders in both `/assets/stylesheets` and `assets/javascripts`. Move all the *application* related assets to the corresponding `/javascripts/app` and `/stylesheets/app` folders.

Add the following code:
To app.js:

```
//= require_tree ./app
```

To app.css:

```
*= require_tree ./app
```

Change your application.html.erb layout's assets links to:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'app', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'app' %>
```

The above code tells the layout to look for app.js and app.css and include what they require. And what they require is everything in the `/app/ folders you have in the different assets folders.

If you push/deploy to Heroku, the application should live in website.com/app (provided you've pointed "website.com" properly to Heroku. See [Reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)).

The next batch of steps is to make the website live within the rails app in the root namespace.

6. Move all the required *website* assets (html, css, javascript) to the corresponding `/javascripts/website` and `/stylesheets/websites` folders in your assets folder.

Add the following code:
To website.js:

```
//= require_tree ./website
```

To app.css:

```
*= require_tree ./website
```

Create a new layout (website.html.erb). It should look very similar to application.html.erb except:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'website', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'website' %>
```

7. Now you can create the controller that will manage the website pages (`WebsiteController`) in `/controllers`.

   ```
   class WebsiteController < ApplicationController

       layout 'website' #we need to tell it which layout to use

       def homepage
       end

       def about
       end

       #basically just create methods/actions for every page on the website
   end
   ```
8. For every action, create a corresponding view in `/views/website`. For example the homepage view should be homepage.html.erb. Also copy and paste the HTML from the website into the right .html.erb files.
9. To tie it all up with routes.

   ```
   root 'website#hompepage'
   get '/about' => 'website#about'
   get '/contact' => 'about#contact'

   #and so on...

   namespace :app do
    # all application routes should be placed in here
   end
   ```
10. Finally make sure to go through all the markup everywhere to replace all `link_to` paths and `src` for img tags. Even the paths for the *app* would need to be changed because all the routes have been changed.

Another option would be to use the [high voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem to add the static website html to your rails app.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just add the website to the Public folder and then conf route to get /app as index#index?

Comment: Also, my problem is that they have the website running as a WordPress inside domains.com, so I think I couldn't just install the whole WordPress website inside heroku. It won't work on your answer because they can create new posts on WordPress. So I can't do that. Thanks so much for your answer tho. It might help other cases.

Comment: @Allan You can't root_to a public html file, you'd still need to create a controller.